# Can't access JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using asp mvc and am returning a json object to my view, and I cannot seem to access any of the properties in the json. Here is my code.

In my Model I have:

```
public string getJson()
{ 
    File a = new File();
    a.Name = "matt";
    a.Path = "c:/adsgadsg/sdagdsag";
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(a);
    //json = "{\"Name\":\"matt\",\"Path\":\"c:/adsgadsg/sdagdsag\"}"   
    return json;
}
```

Then in my javascript I have:

```
function test() {
    var userRegion = '@Model.getJson()';
    var tmp = userRegion.Name;
    var tmp2 = userRegion[0].Name;
    alert(tmp);//undefined
    alert(tmp2);//undefined
}
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks.

**EDIT:**
When I am debugging the javascript, I notice that  '@Model.getJson()'; gets converted to a weird string that CANNOT be parsed by JSON.parse without an exception.

```
 var userRegion = JSON.parse('{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;matt&quot;,&quot;Path&quot;:&quot;c:/adsgadsg/sdagdsag&quot;}');
```

Causes the exception **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &**

Comment: Try using `console.log(userRegion);` after your `var userRegion = ...` line to see what it contains. Also, looking at the console, you should be able to see any exceptions that may occur, also helping to solve your problem. You might notice that `userRegion` is a string, not an object...so you'll need to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: well, a first step would be to add a line like `console.log(userRegion)` in your test() js function, to see what the contents of userRegion actually are.

Comment: First you have to parse the json string to a javascript object. The variable userRegion is a string.

Comment: Also, if you serialize the whole `File` object, you'll have many unwanted fields in there.  try using `string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new {Name=a.Name, Path=a.Path});`

Answer (score 1):

You should first parse the JSON string to a Javascript object. This can be safely done for example with the [Json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library.

UPDATE: Also, you should use the [`Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) function to print out the JSON string, because other way it will be HTML encoded (quotation mark will become &quot;, etc.).

Your code should look like this:

```
function test() {
    var userRegion = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.getJson())');
    var tmp = userRegion.Name;
    //var tmp2 = userRegion[0].Name; this one is not correct
    alert(tmp);//undefined
    //alert(tmp2);//undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that `alert(userRegion );` return `undefined`.

Json can't serialize method and you have to move this code in property inside your model class.

Comment: Well it throws an exception without the alert, and on the line  var userRegion = JSON.parse('@Model.getJson()');

Comment: @JohnEdwards It is possible too. What about changing method to property?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following in MVC3: var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(yourObject); Which will put the JSON string in the correct fields, and then I use a foreach loop to read from events, hope this will guide you in the correct direction.